# Clean up windows registry after InnoSetup uninstallation

Tags: registry, inno-setup

I'm building installer using InnoSetup. After uninstall in my Windows registry appears a key:

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\AppCompatFlags\Compatibility Assistant\Store
```

or (Windows 7)

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\AppCompatFlags\Compatibility Assistant\Persisted
```

with value

```
{appPath}\unins000.exe
```

What is this and what does it do?
I'd like to delete this key after uninstallation and i don't know how to do it. Have u any ideas?

Comment: I noticed that when I delete it in CurUninstallStepChanged procedure it appears after uninstallation

Comment: Probably a flag for application compatibility of the uninstaller itself. Are you running the installer in compatibility mode? / My idea  is to simply list the key in the [Registry] section with flag: uninsdeletekey. See http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=registrysection for more details.